# Save state of a List

Tags: android, android-bundle

How to save a state of my List onSaveInstanceState method?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<RssItem> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        onStartCommand();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList("return", items);
    }

    private void onStartCommand() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RssIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(RssIntentService.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        startService(intent);
    }

    private final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            items = (List<RssItem>) resultData.getSerializable(RssIntentService.ITEMS);
            if (items != null) {
                RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getBaseContext(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Não foi possível encontrar seu feed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

The code returns me the following error:

```
Error:(45, 17) error: method putStringArrayList in class Bundle cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,ArrayList<String>
found: String,List<RssItem>
reason: actual argument List<RssItem> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String> by method invocation conversion
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your List as ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<RssItem> items;
```

And in your `onReceiveResult` method cast using arraylist instead of list:

```
items = (ArrayList<RssItem>) resultData.getSerializable(RssIntentService.ITEMS);
```

Then the code should not throw any error.

Comment: I made changes to the code, but still showing the same error message. May be some error with the class RssItem?

Comment: `actual argument ArrayList<RssItem> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Declare items as      ArrayList<RssItem> items;      and not as ArrayList>String> items